# Will not start after clean install (hangs at disconnected from plymouth) on a Toshiba Satellite

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, toshiba-satellite

I tried upgrading my Toshiba Satellite laptop with NVidia graphics card from 11.04 to 11.10 - it hung and failed, so I reinstalled from scratch as I had no other choice.

When the system boots, it just sits on the black screen saying "disconnected from plymouth".  I've done Ctrl-Alt-F1 and can access the command line without any problems - I tried doing startx from there but it just says something to the effect of nv module not found.

I uninstalled and reinstalled the nvidia-current driver, made no difference.  Also tried dpkg-reconfigure lightdm, and chose gdm.  This worked sort-of, but I can't log in - no matter what I choose (unity, unity2d, gnome) it flashes to a black screen, then back to the login window.

Anyone have any ideas?  I can't put up with using Windows for much longer!

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix it.  For info this appears to have happened because I use an external monitor.  The process to fix was:

Disconnect Monitor, reboot
Used Ctrl-Alt-F1, logged in as myself, ran startx
Prompted by system to install post-release nvidia driver, did that
Rebooted
Plugged in external monitor, ran nvidia settings tool, enabled the external monitor, saved xorg.conf, all working fine.